# What's function of spark checkpoint ".bk" and ".crc" file?

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, crc

When we set the checkpoint directory for spark streaming application, it will generate a directory like this:

```
root@55330815baa7:/usr/local/spark/checkpoint# ll
total 184
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 May 25 16:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x 18  500  500  4096 May 25 16:19 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May 25 16:19 643d19eb-b24b-4664-a865-a263bdd97625/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May 25 16:34 71b2204c-8762-4d75-bb34-f9b1b7a9b530/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May 25 16:19 c946e058-220e-4ae5-8db2-393c00b845d0/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  9658 May 25 16:35 checkpoint-1464193230000
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    84 May 25 16:35 .checkpoint-1464193230000.bk
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    84 May 25 16:35 .checkpoint-1464193230000.crc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  9712 May 25 16:35 checkpoint-1464193236000
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    84 May 25 16:35 .checkpoint-1464193236000.bk
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    84 May 25 16:35 .checkpoint-1464193236000.crc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  9773 May 25 16:35 checkpoint-1464193242000
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  9773 May 25 16:35 checkpoint-1464193242000.bk

-rw-r--r--  1 root root    88 May 25 16:35 .checkpoint-1464193242000.crc
-rw-r--
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May 25 16:35 receivedBlockMetadata/
```

We can find the ".bk" files and '.crc' files, the ".bk" files are the backup files, but for ".crc" files, what is the role? How does it works? Anyone has idea for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CRC stands for **Cyclic Redundancy Check**. It's an **error detecting code** which is used to **detect accidental changes to raw data**.

Example From [CRC on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check):
We'd like to encode a 14-bit message with 3-bit CRC, with polynomial x^3 + x + 1

Assuming we have this message: `11010011101100`(14 bits)
And we use a polynomial divisor: `1011`(which stands for x^3 + x + 1)

The computations are **XOR**.

1. First we pad zeros to corresponds the bit length of encoded message(14+3=17 bits):
   `11010011101100 000 <--- input right padded by 3 bits`
   `1011               <--- divisor (4 bits) = x³ + x + 1`
   `------------------`

   `01100011101100 000 <--- result`
2. Iteratively compute a new result by moving divisor 1 bit (or more) to the right in each step:
   `01100011101100 000 <--- result of step 1`

     `1011              <--- divisor`

   `00111011101100 000`

      `1011`

   `00010111101100 000`

        `1011`

   `00000001101100 000 <--- note that the divisor moves over to align with the next 1 in`

               `1011             the dividend (since quotient for that step was zero)`

   `00000000110100 000      (in other words, it doesn't necessarily move one bit per`

                 `1011            iteration)`

   `00000000011000 000`

                   `1011`

   `00000000001110 000`

                     `1011`

   `00000000000101 000`

                      `101 1`

   `------------------`

   `00000000000000 100 <--- remainder (3 bits). Division algorithm stops here as dividend`

                                             `is equal to zero.`

Since the leftmost divisor bit zeroed every input bit it touched, when this process ends the only bits in the input row that can be nonzero are the 3 bits at the right-hand end of the row.

These 3 bits are the remainder of the division step, and will also be the value of the CRC function (unless the chosen CRC specification calls for some postprocessing).

**The validation of received message**

The validity of a received message can easily be verified by performing the above calculation again, this time with the check value added instead of zeroes. The remainder should equal zero if there are no detectable errors.

`11010011101100 100 <--- input with check value`

`1011               <--- divisor`

`01100011101100 100 <--- result`

  `1011              <--- divisor ...`

`00111011101100 100`


`......`


`00000000001110 100`

                  `1011`

`00000000000101 100`

                   `101 1`

`------------------`

                             `0 <--- remainder`

Comment: what about the .bk files -- what is their purpose?

Comment: Is there any way so that these files are not created?